# how to dismiss a static card in Google glass after X seconds?

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm adding a static card to my google glass timeline.

How can I dismiss this card after 2 seconds?

Is it possible to delay-dismiss even if the activity which created this card has finished already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a combination of [Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) and [TimelineManager.delete(long)](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/timeline/TimelineManager#delete%28long%29)

Example:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run () {
        mTimelineManager.delete(cardId);
    }
}, 5000);
```

If you are using a Service then you can do this even after the Activity has finished.